# How to have multiple activities use same tracking activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am writing a fitness app and I am not sure how to implement my next step. I have an activity for each muscle group (chest, back, biceps, triceps, etc) and each of those activities has a list view that list 15+ exercises for each muscle.

I have another activity that is the "tracking" activity where the user can input their weight and reps for the selected exercise.

I want each of these listview items to go to this "tracking" activity when clicked, but also have a way to store the data for each exercise separately. How should I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Intents to navigate between pages.

When a button is clicked on any of the activities say `track`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ChestActivity.this, TrackActivity.class);
i.putExtra("CameFrom", "chest");
startActivity(i);
```

Go to the tracking activity.

Read the measurements, send it using intents putExtra method.

Use that data appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! In the putExtra can I use the ID of one of the list items or can I only put what activity it is from?

Comment: You can use a `String` key-value pair. Configure it accordingly.